# Use COUNT, but only for a specific value

Tags: php, html, sql, sql-server

I have a table that has matches saved in it, and I want to generate a table that shows the current standings out of it. So far my code looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cname, COUNT(cname) AS games, **COUNT(points WHERE points=3) AS wins**, 1, 0, SUM(goalsscored)-SUM(goalsconceded) AS goaldiff, SUM(po$
FROM pmatch
GROUP BY cname
ORDER BY point DESC, goaldiff DESC
```

I have every match saved with the number of points a team got in that match. So I simply have to count every match where a team gets 3 points to have the number of wins, 1 points to have the number of draws and 0 points to have the number of loses.

However, the COUNT command doesn't work as I want it to work. In the **bold** part you see that I want to count every match where a team got 3 points. How do I do this properly?

Big thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `CASE`:

```
SELECT cname, COUNT(cname) AS games, COUNT(case when points=3 then 1 end) AS wins, 1, 0, SUM(goalsscored)-SUM(goalsconceded) AS goaldiff
FROM pmatch
GROUP BY cname
ORDER BY wins DESC,  -- probably
     goaldiff DESC
```

Comment: `Distinct` is useless in that query

Comment: Thank you!! I use the COUNT how you wrote it, and it works perfectly

Answer (score 3):

Use `CASE` expression.

**Query**

```
SELECT cname, 
COUNT(cname) AS games, 
SUM(CASE points WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS wins,
SUM(CASE points WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS draws,
SUM(CASE points WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS loses,
SUM(goalsscored)-SUM(goalsconceded) AS goaldiff
FROM pmatch
GROUP BY cname
ORDER BY 3 DESC, 6 DESC;
```